Probability: Bayes theorem and priors
In the context of a typical conditional probability question e.g. chance of John going outside if he sees clouds etc, how is the prior probability not always 0.5.
If prior means before any updating information, i.e. before John sees the cloud, isn't it always 50/50?

John may very well be a person who generally likes to stay inside regardless of the weather. In that case, the probability that he goes outside during the day could be less than $\frac{1}{2}$. On the other hand, it is possible that he could be the type of person to get cabin fever and want to go outside frequently despite the weather he might encounter. Then the probability that he goes outside during the day could be more than $\frac{1}{2}$.
Therefore, the probability that he goes outside is not necessarily $\frac{1}{2}$. It is dependent on how frequently he tends to go outside rather than stay inside, which may be unbalanced. To say it is $\frac{1}{2}$ is to potentially neglect his inherent affinity for going outside.
